# Advice for last year math undergrad.

Tags: soft-question, advice, online-resources

I am in my last year of my math undergraduate degree.  I am taking Theoretical Statistics and a Dynamic Modelling course, and I need 2 more courses after these.  While I received very strong grades in everything I did at a community college, I am doing less well at the university.

Being a single mom with a job, I have no time for the extra studying required and I am not a genius. I am now at the bottom of my classes, and I am lost and discouraged. This material is dense and fast paced for me.  I've been in the work force for 15 years also doing retail/labor.

My question is for advice.  Should I be concerned, is this a sign that math isn't my thing, should I push through with low grades and focus on managing stress?

Comment: Personal thought - math is a BROAD field of study, with all sorts of specific subfields and particular areas of study. I, for example, tend to struggle at the more "applicable" stuff - differential equations, modeling, physics, etc. - but do relatively okay with the "purer" math - such as algebra and analysis. If you're looking for extra classes to fill out your courseload, and I assume you want math courses, I would suggest straying away from stuff you know you struggle with, and stick closer to stuff you know you're good at. Or you could always try something you've never delved into before.

Comment: The point being, you might be good at some kinds of math, and not so much at others. Try to figure out what you're good at, and what you enjoy, and play to those strengths.

Comment: Questions seeking personal advice for choosing a course, academic program, career path, etc should not be asked on math.se. Such questions should be directed to those employed by the institution in question, or other qualified individuals who know your specific circumstances.